# Prove operation on the set binary relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An operation on the set $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$ is given in the table below.
Which of the properties commutative, associative, and identity does the operation and
the set have? Does this set with ∗ have inverses? If so, identify them.

[image]

I know that to prove the question

Commutative $bc=cb$

Associative $a(bc) = (ab)c$

Identity $ka=a=ak$

But Im difficulty in reading the set and finding the inverse. What would be the solution of set $a$, set $b$ and set $c$

Answer (score 1):

Let denote your operation with a star.

1. It is **not** commutative, since $c * b  = b$ and $b * c = c$.
2. The element $d$ is a neutral element since $x * d = x = d * x$ for all $x$.
3. It is **not** associative since $(c*b)*a = b * a = d$, but $c * (b * a) = c * d = c$.
4. Every element has an inverse, since $a*b = d = b*a$, $c*e = d = e*c$ and $d*d =d$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$. Note that d is the neutral element: $\forall k \in X \; k * d = d * k = k$. So to prove that the elements in the set have inverses, you have to show that $\forall k \in X \; \exists r \in X : k * r = d$, (because you have commutation), and it is obvious that this is true.

Comment: Could you explain a little more please. The standard equations use elements such as a,b c to prove question like these. In this instance, what would those elements represent?

Comment: An element $t \in X$ has an inverse, if there exists some element $r \in X$, so that $t * r = r * t =$ neutral element. In your case, d is the neutral element, and $a * b = b * a = d$, $c * e = e * c = d$, $d * d = d$. You can read more about inverse elements [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element)

Comment: I am afraid that the operation is not commutative. Moreover, you say nothing about associativity.